# Creating an object using a constructor with and without `new`

Tags: javascript, object

I have noticed I can create the same object using a constructor in two different ways.

```
var myObj = Object()

var myObj = new Object()
```

I can add properties to both using these methods. `myObj.age = 1`  and `myObj['age'] = 1`. The properties of both can be accesed the same way.

So what is the actual difference between these two ways I created `myObj`?  Also is one of these the better way to create an object?

Comment: [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

Comment: the "this" pointer within the constructor/methods is window-object or undefined without new-operator, depends on strict-mode on or off. When new-operator is used then "this" is the instance.

Comment: Without using new-operator you would add a property to the window-object and not to an instance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that the first one simply calls `Object()` as a function, within the scope of the `window` object.

The second one actually instantiates a new object. It's the one you want to use to create an object.

The difference may not be obvious with the `Object()` function, but let's say you create your own type, like so:

```
function User(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
var u1 = User("John");
var u2 = new User("Jane");

console.log(u1); // *undefined* because `User()` doesn't return anything.
console.log(this.name); // John
console.log(window.name); // John
console.log(u2.name); // "Jane"
```

The `Object` function itself is a special case--it does create a new Object. But since most functions don't work that way, it's good to get in the habit of using the `new` keyword when instantiating things. If you're just creating a plain old `Object`, on the other hand, most people prefer the more concise syntax:

```
var myObj = {};
```

Comment: so, `console.log(this.name); // John` and `console.log(window.name); // John` are both things that I should not be able to do?

Comment: @Vader: Right. That implies that the `User` function just set a *global variable*, which is bad practice. If you tried to create three users this way, each new user's name would simply overwrite the previous one. All you're doing at that point is setting properties on a global object, not creating new ones.

Answer (score 2):

The first statement is a *function* call, meaning that `myObj` will get whatever is returned in the `Object()` function. As it happens, the function `Object()` will provide you with a reference to an `Object` object, whereas 'normal' constructors will not.

See f.e. the following:

```
function O(){
  this.bla= "bla";
  return this;
}
```

Calling `O()` here will yield a reference to `window`, not to an instance of `O`.

Comment: so what does the function call `Object()` return? and why is it a function?

Comment: This would be an instance of an empty object, like `{}` would yield.

Comment: but isn't an empty object what I would want? I can add the properties like this `myObj.prop = 1`

Comment: Creating an empty object is a common practice, for example as a first step in building an 'associative array'.